# JQuery focus event

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and trying to do some animation on h1 tag in header when page loads.But it doesn't seems to be working.
I think it is not going in the load function.Can anyone tell me why?
Is there any difference between calling .on('load',function(){}) and simply load(function(){})?

```
<html>
<head>      
    <title>UI Design Assignment</title>
<style>
        #header{
            background-color : #5555FF;
            width : 100%;
            height: 8%;
            text-align : center;
            color : white;
            box-shadow : 0 0 25px #5555FF;
        }
        #imagediv{
            height: 80%;
            width : 15%;
            padding-top : 50px;
            padding-left : 85px;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
            float : left;               
        }           
        #registrationdiv{
            width : 65%;
            height: 80%;                
            font-family : Calibri;
            font-size : 20px;
            border-radius : 2;
            float : left;
        }
        #registrationtable{
            position : relative;
            margin : 18px;
            align : center;
            background-color : #AAA;
            overflow-y : scroll;
            box-shadow : 0 0 17px gray;
            border-radius : 5%;
        }
        #footer{
            background-color : #5555FF;
            width : 100%;
            height: 8%;
            color : white;
            text-align : center;                
            margin : 0px auto 0px auto;
            padding : 2px;
            box-shadow : 0 0 25px #5555FF;
            clear : both;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#registrationimg" ).mouseenter(function() {

                $( this ).fadeOut( 1000 );
            });
            $( "#registrationimg" ).mouseleave(function() {
                $( this ).fadeIn( 1000 );
            });
            $("h1").load(function(){
                $(this).css({
                    "left": "500px",
                    "-webkit-transform":"rotate(360deg)",
                    "-webkit-transition": "1s"});
            });
        });

        function submitform(){

            if(document.getElementById("iaccept").checked==false){
                alert("You cannot go ahead without accepting the terms and conditions.");
            }
            else{
                alert("Registration completed.");
            }
        }   
        function resetform(){
            window.reset();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">           
        <h1>USER REGISTRATION</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="imagediv">
        <img id="registrationimg" src="registration.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="registrationdiv"><center>      
    <form name="registrationform"  onsubmit="submitform()">
        <table id="registrationtable" cellspacing="10">
            <tr><td>Email <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="email" name="email" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="password" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Confirm Password <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="password" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td>First Name <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="text"  required></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name : </td><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address : </td><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>City : </td><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>State : </td><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Country : <font color="red">*</font></td><td><input type="text" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Phone : </td><td><input type="tel" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Zipcode : </td><td><input type="number" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Date of Birth <font color="red">*</font> : </td><td><input type="date" name="email" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">By submitting, I agree that all information entered was done accurately & truthfully.</td></tr>
            <tr><td>I accept <input type="checkbox" id="iaccept"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit"></td><td><input type="reset" name="Reset"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form></center>
    </div>
    <center></center>
    <div id="footer">Copyright &copy; <a href="https://harbingergroup.com"><font color="#00F"><b>Harbinger Group</b></font></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `load` handler for the `h1`; it's already loaded. Using `$('h1').load(...)` means "do something when the `h1` loads (for example, via AJAX)." But this code runs after the page has loaded, and you never reload the `h1`, so that code never runs.

Instead, just apply the CSS directly. It's in a `$(document).ready(...)`, so it will run when the page loads. Here's how you do it:

```
$("h1").css({
     "left": "500px",
     "-webkit-transform":"rotate(360deg)",
     "-webkit-transition": "1s"
});
```

[Working demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v505svd0/)

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: P.S. The code in my answer does still need to be in the `$(document).ready(...)` block.

Comment: Can you see the animation?

Comment: Yep. In the fiddle I posted, it rotates over the course of 1 second.